# Hidden Objects Wont Un-Hide?

Tags: objects, object-mode, visibility

So I'm having an odd problem, I've spent a decent chink of today making a hollow knight charm in 3D and the way I made it involved making a lot of separate objects and a lot of the time I end up hiding certain objects and for whatever reason, they aren't un-hiding.

You can see in the outliner that they still exist and in the properties menu that they are still there and have dimensions and whatnot, but they don't respond to alt + H nor do they respond to the same command via the object menu. I have no idea what happened here but that was alot of work that id rather not have lost so if anyone has any clue please respond asap.

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Comment: Look at the top left of the screen. You are in **Local mode**. Only the selected object is visible. To exit local mode press the / key in the numeric pad.